Add border to parent row cell
My problem is:

When I select YES - I have border line around cell only in cell with checkbox YES - I need change it to select all rows.

When I select YES - I need show error message - but it's not working. How can i change it?




// YES
$('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_0"]').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().css({
    'border': '2px solid #da4f49'
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.medical_error_message').html('Error - you not like this');
});
// NO
$('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_1"]').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().css({
    'border': '1px solid #ddd',
    'color': '#000000',
    'font-weight': 'normal'
  });
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.medical_error_message').html('');
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question"><b>1. Do you like</b></td>
      <td>YES</td>
      <td>NOW</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question">
        1. Red hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td style="border: 2px solid rgb(218, 79, 73);"><label for="id_0-medical_question1_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_0">
     YES</label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question1_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question">
        2. Blond hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_0">
     YES
    </label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>




Please present your problem before you dump code on us, and format it properly. Walls of text are difficult to interpret. See [ask] for more tips. Also ask just one question per post.

Note that I added a closing b tag in your first table cell so the auto-formatter would work properly in the demo snippet.

Protip: Selectors with multiple IDs are usually unnecessary as an ID may only exist once in a document anyway. The leading ID is redundant.

Your jQuery can be MUCH simplified using a CSS class and delegation
Note the table css to make the row actually get a border


$('[id*="medical_question"]').on('click', function() {
  const yes = $(this).val() === "1";
  $(this).closest('tr')
    .toggleClass('normal', !yes)
    .toggleClass('red', yes)
    .find('.medical_error_message').html(yes ? 'Error - you not like this' : '');
});
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.red {
  border: 2px solid #da4f49;
}

tr.normal {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question"><b>1. Do you like</b></td>
      <td>YES</td>
      <td>NO</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="normal">
      <td class="medical_question">
        1. Red hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question1_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_0">
     YES</label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question1_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="normal">
      <td class="medical_question">
        2. Blond hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_0">
     YES
    </label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>




For 1, the problem is the $(this).parent().parent().css( which is pointing to the td where the radio button is, not the tr (row). You can use $(this).parent().parent().parent().css( but there is a better way - use $(this).closest('tr') instead to find the first tr where your radio button is.
For 2, it is pointing to the td of the radio buttons not the td where your medical_error_message is. Use $(this).closest('tr').find('.medical_error_message') instead since it's unique in each row.
Another thing, changing the border of your tr won't reflect unless you set the style of the table to border-collapse: collapse;.
Here is the modified code:


// YES
$('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_0"]').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').css({
    'border': '2px solid #da4f49'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.medical_error_message').html('Error - you not like this');
});
// NO
$('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_1"]').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').css({
    'border': '1px solid #ddd',
    'color': '#000000',
    'font-weight': 'normal'
  });
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.medical_error_message').html('');
});
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question"><b>1. Do you like</b></td>
      <td>YES</td>
      <td>NOW</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question">
        1. Red hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question1_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_0">
     YES</label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question1_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question1" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question1_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="medical_question">
        2. Blond hair
        <p class="medical_error_message"></p>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_0"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="1" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_0">
     YES
    </label>
      </td>

      <td><label for="id_0-medical_question2_1"><input type="radio" name="0-medical_question2" value="0" required="" id="id_0-medical_question2_1">
     NO</label>
      </td>
    </tr>




I think your jQuery is wrong. You need to update the jQuery selectors to target all rows when selecting YES.
Here's your updated code:
$(document).ready(function() {
  // YES
  $('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_0"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.medical_question').css({
        'border': '2px solid #da4f49'
      });
      $('.medical_error_message').html('Error - you do not like this');
    }
  });

  // NO
  $('[id^="id_0-medical_question"][id$="_1"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.medical_question').css({
        'border': '1px solid #ddd',
        'color': '#000000',
        'font-weight': 'normal'
      });
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.medical_error_message').html('');
    }
  });
});

